# Adverbs of degree with reduplicated adjective phrases?

Tags: grammar, usage, adjectives

Why is it not necessary to use 很 (or other adverbs of degree) to link nouns and adjectives when you reduplicate the adjective, and instead use a 的 after the adjective?

For example:

> 你的女朋友高高的。
>
> 她们漂漂亮亮的。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 很 as an adverb (very) only applies to adjective, never noun
- A reduplicated adjective emphasizes itself similar to adding "quite" (颇/相当)

A reduplicated adjective cannot also use "very" because a reduplicated adjective *emphasizes itself*, similar to adding the adverb "quite".

Example:

> 他**很强壮** = He is (very strong)
>
> **强强壮壮的**他 = He who is (quite strong)

We can describe a man "very strong" or "quite strong" but not at same time, because they are different degree of superlative. 很 (very) is stronger than 颇 (quite). Is he very strong or quite strong?

"他(很)(强强壮壮的)" translated into English would be "He is very quite strong", which is not grammatical.

Comment: Ok, I see you can't use很 in this kind of phrases. But what pattern can you use for reduplicated adjectives: "Red Adj + 的 + Noun" or "Noun + Red Adj + 的“? I did read this second pattern so got confused.

Comment: The difference between " 强强壮壮的他 " and "他强强壮壮的 " -- The former is a simple "adj +n" phrase;  The latter seems incomplete. It would be more natural to write "他强强壮壮的,  不用看医生" than just "他强强壮壮的"

Comment: 他强强壮壮的 is a [ topic + comment] sentence,  in  which 他 is the topic and 强强壮壮的 is the comment

Answer (score 1):

That reduplication pattern of adjectives is a ***cutie*** way to express ***quite***.  E. g.  她的眼睛大大的。他的个子高高的。

Well, 她的眼睛很大 and 他的个子很高 don't have that effect.

We don't say 她的眼睛很大大的, which means 很 doesn't work with this reduplication pattern.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things going here, the reduplication， and a sentence structure that goes N  + Adj + 的. I think of these sentences as:

你的女朋友高高的 = 他的女朋友 （是一个）高高的 （女朋友）

NB: The N + Adj + 的 structure is not limited to reduplicated adjectives.